# architcture 86_64 error

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Getting this error:

[image]

which seems to be connected to this, but have no idea why:

```
// Inline
inline float onsetsds_phase_rewrap(float phase);
inline float onsetsds_phase_rewrap(float phase){
    return (phase>MINUSPI && phase<PI) ? phase : phase + TWOPI * (1.f + floorf((MINUSPI - phase) * INV_TWOPI));
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is that defined? In a source file or a header? If it is a source file make sure that it is part of compile sources.

Comment: It is in the .c file. I've removed the `inline` bit and now it works. Do you think that matters?

Comment: Is the function only referenced from within the same C file? If not what does the declaration look like in the header. You have to make sure all of the declarations (should only be 1) match the definition.

Comment: Yes, the function is only referenced from within the same file.